# Why are castrated animals slaughtered as Kosher beef?

Tags: halacha, kashrut-kosher, animals, noachide-laws, tzaar-baalei-chayyim

Castration and dehorning of cattle is the common practice in the cattle industry. This a violation a basic Noahide Law ref Tractate Sanhedrin 56a-b:

> שבע מצות נצטוו בני נח ...רבי חידקא אומר אף על הסירוס
>
> Seven commandments were given to the sons of Noah... Rabbi Chidka said they were also commanded not to castrate animals.

All men today that are Bnei Noah are required to follow this command. I refuse to castrate and dehorn my cattle and get a big reduction in sale price for them at the local sale barns. Most of all male slaughtered animals in the US have been castrated, dehorned if not polled by mixed breeding and then fattened on Kilayim-(mingled seed) (GMO) feeds with herbicide residues. Why are these animals slaughtered as kosher beef?

Answer (score 6):

**Castration** of an animal is forbidden to Gentiles (according to most opinions) so a Jew cannot tell him to do so. If he does he is forbidden to eat that animal. But if the gentile has already castrated the animal it is permitted for a Jew to eat that animal.

The Shulchan Aruch (Rabbinic Authority) Even Haezer 5,14 says:

> אסור לומר לכותי לסרס בהמה שלנו. ואם לקחה הוא מעצמו וסרסה, מותר. ואם הערים ישראל בדבר זה, קונסין אותו
>   It is forbidden to tell a Gentile to castrate an animal, but if the Gentile castrated it himself without consent form any Jew it is fully permitted to have benefit from. But **if the Jew told the Gentile to castrate the Animal for him he cannot benefit from the animal as a penalty.**

Chelkas Mechokek (Rabbinic authority) elaborates:

> ישראל אחר מותר לאכול אף על גב שהוא בכלל תעבתי לך מ"מ מדאסור לגבוה ש"מ להדיוט שרי מרדכי פ' ש"ש וישראל שסירס או שסירס העכו"ם בשבילו משמע דאסור לאכול ממנו
>   We only punish him since *he* told the Gentile to castrate the Animal or castrated it himself he cannot eat it, but **we don't punish other Jews that were not involved in telling the gentile to castrate the Animal i.e *they* can eat those castrated animals** as long as it was Slaughtered properly.

***Kilayim***: A Gentile is not commanded regading cross breed of seeds .
Rather a Gentile is only commanded regarding crossbreeding trees for fruit, and cross breeding animals species. Rambam Melachim 10,6:

> מִפִּי הַקַּבָּלָה שֶׁבְּנֵי נֹחַ אֲסוּרִין בְּהַרְבָּעַת בְּהֵמָה וּבְהַרְכָּבַת אִילָן בִּלְבַד
>   A Noachide is commanded not to crossbreed animals and trees

So since a gentile *can* make genetically modified seeds and feed his animals, those animals are fully permitted for a Jew to buy as no transgression has happened.